# Use .NET Assemblies in Native C++ Applications

Tags: .net, c++

I followed the instruction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb892742 about how to use .NET Assemblies in Native C++ Applications. Now my question is:
Suppose I want to create a C++ dll where I call a .NET assembly in a similar way.
Should it be possible to use LoadLibrary of this dll in a C++ native app?
Or should the C++ native app in this case also be linked with the /clr option?
The second question is: what is the penalty of using the /clr flag in a C++ native app?
Performance, Compile-time, Run-time, ... ?

Comment: This question is far too vague to give an accurate answer.  Why don't you just try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load cli c++ dll with LoadLibrary from non cli application (have done this from Delphi application).
As my cli dll is small, can not make any statements about penalties.

Comment: Well I am able to call LoadLibrary and link it in, but as soon as I call a C++ function that calls the .NET layer I get the error:
The exception unknown software exception (0xc0000409) occurred

Comment: Just made c++ test project, and it loaded cli dll calling System::Console::WriteLine("CLI"); It worked without any problems

Comment: The unknown software exception I got was due to a reason described in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93770/eefileloadexception-when-using-c-classes-in-cwin32-app 
: the CLR won't look for managed DLLs in the path of the unmanaged DLL and will only look for it where the executable is. (or in the GAC).