# using c# com wrapped dll in c++ throws class not registered

Tags: c#, c++, com

I am getting a  "Class not registered" exception when i try to instantiate a c# dll wrapped by com using CreateInstance call.

Following is the stack trace:

```
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashGet\fgmgr.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\acfc1391e45fedd2a359778ea57d914c\mscorlib.ni.dll'. 
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x75E7B9BC in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x004BDACC.
First-chance exception at 0x75E7B9BC in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x75E7B9BC in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x75E7B9BC in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93770/eefileloadexception-when-using-c-sharp-classes-in-cwin32-app help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the C# COM class is not registered. Use RegAsm.exe to register the C# COM DLL.

Comment: I have executed the Regasm command and it results in saying the Types registered successfully but however I got the following warnings st(List) Warning: There is no marshaling support for nested arrays.

Comment: The code may still work without marshaling, but it's generally unsafe. I suggest finding an alternative to using nested arrays. Anyway, does it run successfully?

Comment: I am having the same issue no progress. I am thinking of writing a custom wrapper around the code.