# Unable to load function from c# dll using a c++/cli wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli

This is my first time with calling functions from c# dlls.

I have made a c# wrapper(c++/cli) to call c# functions from c++. This wrapper itself is a dll which I want to use in my main code. Below are the wrapper.h and wrapper.cpp files. CSharpWrapper is the abstract class that inherits the base class ImageTool. At the end of the header file I am exporting a factory of the wrapper class.

**wrapper.h**

```
#define Export_Wrapper

#ifdef Export_Wrapper
#define _DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define _DLLImport __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // Export_Wrapper

class CSharpWrapperPrivate;

class _DLLExport CSharpWrapper : public ImageTool
{
public:
    CSharpWrapper();
    ~CSharpWrapper();

    int Initialize();
    int Deinitialize();
    cv::Mat AcquireImg(double positionX, double positionY);

private:
    CSharpWrapperPrivate* _private;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ImageTool* __cdecl createFactory()
{
    return new CSharpWrapper;
}
```

**wrapper.cpp**

```
class CSharpWrapperPrivate
{
public:
    msclr::auto_gcroot<ImageDistiller^> ImageAPI;
};

CSharpWrapper::CSharpWrapper()
{
}

CSharpWrapper::~CSharpWrapper()
{
    delete _private;
}

int CSharpWrapper::Initialize()
{
    _private = new CSharpWrapperPrivate();
    _private->ImageAPI = gcnew ImageDistiller();
    return _private->ImageAPI->Initialize();
}

int CSharpWrapper::Deinitialize()
{
    return _private->ImageAPI->Deinitialize();
}

cv::Mat CSharpWrapper::AcquireImg(double positionX, double positionY)
{
    Mat img = _private->ImageAPI->AcquireImg(positionX, positionY);
}/**/
```

In the wrapper.cpp file, visual studio is able to suggest the functions available in the c# dll. The following is the main.cpp code where I am trying to call functions through this wrapper.

**main.cpp**

```
typedef ImageTool*(__cdecl *ImgFactory)();

ImageTool* instance_imgcapture;
HINSTANCE dll_imgcapture_handle;

int main()
{
    dll_imgcapture_handle = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("wrapper.dll"));
    if (!dll_imgcapture_handle) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to load wrapper DLL!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ImgFactory zximgcapturefactory = reinterpret_cast<ImgFactory>(::GetProcAddress(dll_imgcapture_handle, "createFactory"));
    if (!zximgcapturefactory)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to load factory from wrapper.dll!!\n";
        ::FreeLibrary(dll_imgcapture_handle);
        return 1;
    }

    instance_imgcapture = zximgcapturefactory();
    instance_imgcapture->Initialize();

    return 1;
}
```

Now, when I run main.cpp, it is able to create dll_imgcapture_handle and ImgFactory. But it gives the following error  when instance_imgcapture->Initialize() is called:

**Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD20B5A388 (KernelBase.dll) in wrapper.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80070002, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD03580000).**

I tried this method to load dlls (as in main.cpp) with other c++ dlls - it works.
I tried to check if there are any missing dlls using dependency_walker- there were none.
I have included the correct opencv libraries and they work correctly. I have included the path to the dlls and libs in the project properties and added the lib names in Linker->Input.

Can you please help me to debug this problem.

Comment: Did you try to debug this?

Comment: @AlexF I tried debugging by setting breakpoints. But when I reach Initialize(), I just get the exception mentioned above. I also get the following error in the output window:  Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00......   Because of this error I used dependency_walker to see if any dependency is missing, but everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Can you step into Initialize call? See also the Output window - it shows, what libraries are loaded. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93770/eefileloadexception-when-using-c-sharp-classes-in-cwin32-app

Comment: @AlexF the link you mentioned above worked. I first changed  the "Debugger Type" to "Mixed" mode in ConfigurationProperties->Debugging. This resulted in a more detailed error which mentions clearly which dependency is missing. And I copied the dependencies in the Debug folder and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Such is the risk of calling managed code from native C++.  Managed code *really* likes throwing exceptions when anything goes wrong, but there isn't anybody around to catch them and display a helpful diagnostic.  0xE0434352 is all you know.  There is always a good reason for 0x80070002, the just-in-time compiler often has a hard time finding any dependent managed DLLs.  The kind of problem that you solve by putting *all* of the required DLLs in the same directory as the EXE or providing a foo.exe.config file.  Debug by changing the Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake related to the dependencies. Since I am trying to call managed code from unmanaged, the output produced by the debugger does not clearly mention the error and just outputs "Unhandled exception at 0x00....". I used dependency walker to look for any missing dependencies but it cannot find anything probably because I am trying to load the dll manually in the main code.

One of the answers in the link mentioned by AlexF solved my problem.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31723080/5484662)

I first changed the "Debugger Type" to "Mixed" mode in configurationProperties->Debugging. This resulted in a more detailed error which mentions clearly which dependency is missing. And I copied the dependencies in the Debug folder and it works.

Comment: Dependency Walker has a Profile feature which can give you more runtime information. .NET's Fusion Log Viewer is also helpful.