# First-chance exception, Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location

Tags: c#, c++, dll, first-chance-exception

I am working on a C++ DLL that is part of a much larger project, the application is written in C#.

Recently I am getting a Microsoft Visual Studio error displayed.  I am debugging the project with Visual Studio, I've attached to the process.  I have a break point in DllMain, but it crashes before it gets there, a dialog is displayed containing:

```
    First-change exception at 0x74372ea2 in ........Service.exe:
    Microsoft C++ exception EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x039bc4d4..
```

If I click on the Break button the Call stack is displayed:

> > [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]
> >         KernelBase.dll!74372ea2()
> >         clr.dll!50bc454d()
> >         clr.dll!50afc3ee()
> >         clr.dll!50afc41d()
> >         clr.dll!50afc440()
> >         clr.dll!50b415a4()
> >         clr.dll!50b1a8dc()
> >         clr.dll!50b1a476()
> >         clr.dll!50b1e0c4()
> >         clr.dll!50b161b0()
> >         clr.dll!50b238aa()
> >         clr.dll!50b1f739()
> >         clr.dll!50b1f739()
> >         clr.dll!50b1c090()
> >         clr.dll!50b22caf()
> >         clrjit.dll!68971939()
> >         clrjit.dll!689922a5()
> >         clrjit.dll!68989fed()
> >         clrjit.dll!689749d5()
> >         clr.dll!50b1fecf()
> >         clr.dll!50b1ffac()
> >         clr.dll!50b1fff1()
> >         clr.dll!50b2024f()
> >         kernel32.dll!76933a61()
> >         kernel32.dll!76933a61()
> >         clr.dll!50adf405()
> >         clr.dll!50adf35f()
> >         clr.dll!50b209bf()
> >         clr.dll!50b21780()
> >         clr.dll!50adef11()
> >         mscorlib.ni.dll!78fda29d()
> >         mscorlib.ni.dll!790214a2()
> >         mscorlib.ni.dll!790213d6()
> >         mscorlib.ni.dll!79021391()
> >         mscorlib.ni.dll!78fda1f8()
> >         clr.dll!50adea56()
> >         clr.dll!50af93ef()
> >         clr.dll!50af9673()
> >         clr.dll!50c3ecfd()
> >         clr.dll!50afb213()
> >         clr.dll!50afb27d()
> >         clr.dll!50ae1c81()
> >         clr.dll!50adf405()
> >         clr.dll!50ae1c81()
> >         clr.dll!50ae1e80()
> >         clr.dll!50bd4917()
> >         kernel32.dll!769395e4()
> >         ntdll.dll!774d241a()
> >         ntdll.dll!774d23e9()

What can I do to help me trace where the problem is?

[Edit] based on recommendation I did the following:

```
    Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols
```

I specified the (.pdb) location which was the same as the DLL location:

```
    C:\Edwards\Scada\Agent Service\
```

I also checked the path to make sure that it was correct, sadly no difference.

[Edit 2] Bit more information, the C# part of this project is being developed in Visual Studio 2010.  The C++ part is in Visual Studio 2008.  I have no control over this.

Comment: [EEFileLoadException when using C# classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93770/eefileloadexception-when-using-c-sharp-classes-in-cwin32-app)

Comment: Make a stack trace like this readable by enabling the symbol server: Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.  Debug managed exceptions by changing the debugger type: Project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type = Mixed.  The 98% case here is the just-in-time compiler (clrjit.dll) not being able to find an assembly, FileNotFound is the 3rd boolean value.  Ensure that the error handling in CLR hosting code is adequate to produce a decent diagnostic for such a basic mishap.

Comment: @HansPassant, tried this, no change, I also checked the path I supplied to the dialog, and its correct with a PDB for each DLL.

Comment: Well, of course there is a change when you enable the symbol server.  Every shortcut you take costs you an extra day to solve this problem.  Google "what is a first-chance exception" to find out what to do next.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you, I'm no further forward tho.